# Cannot use Android phone in fastboot mode

Tags: fastboot, samsung-galaxy-on7

I have a Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1.

On my computer (Windows 7, 32-bit), I have adb and fastboot installed. I can work on my phone properly from adb. But the problem starts in fastboot mode.

When I put my phone in bootloader mode, the computer takes the phone to be a modem. There are several videos that show how the driver problems can be solved, but once my computer identifies the device as modem, I cannot do anything else, as it is reluctant to install the Android Bootloader Interface drivers for my phone, saying they are the ones meant for a modem.

I have even tried to stop auto installation of drivers, but even then the device is recognised as a modem.

Is there any way I can stop my computer from recognising the device as a modem?

Comment: There is no fastboot mode for Samsung devices. Download mode (Odin/Heimdall) might be what you're after (which uses proprietary drivers).

Comment: That's sad, and I didn't know about that. You mean to say after I put my phone in bootloader mode, I cannot use fastboot, but I have to use some software like Odin, right?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. That mode is meant for flashing various binaries: recovery, firmware, root packages etc... But using a tool that supports Samsung protocols